# Обработка xml ответа php

Tags: php, xml, api

Как выводить информацию с такого ответа ? 3 строка почему-то не работает.

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://resources.finance.ua/ua/public/currency-cash.xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$xml->organization[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас пропущен один уровень organizations, кроме того, id - это атрибут, т.е. обращаться к нему нужно как к элементу ассоциативного массива

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents('http://resources.finance.ua/ua/public/currency-cash.xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
echo $xml->organizations->organization[0]['id'];
```

Comment: Можете подсказать, что почитать по работе с xml ? В статьях из гугла все очень просто, а хочу разобраться полностью.

Comment: @M.Ivashchuk На самом деле технология XML довольно объемна, включает XPath, XQuery, XLST и многое другое. Лучше всего добыть какую-нибудь книгу полностью посвященную XML. Основы и XPath будут актуальны даже в книгах 10-15 летней давности, для XLST лучше использовать книги посвежее, которые охватывают XLST 2.0. Сопутствующие технологии вроде CSS лучше вообще изучать отдельно. Могу посоветовать Д. Хантер, Дж. Рафтер и другие. XML. Базовый курс. 4-е изд. Вильямс, 2009 - 1344 стрницы, полностью посвященные XML :)